# Android Tinder like view with buttons

Tags: android, animation, swipe, swipeview

In my project i'm using this https://github.com/ecstasy2/tinder-card-stack library for tinder like cards swipe animation. It work good, but it doesn't support removing top view by button click, like or dislike. I lost a lot of time trying to make some callbacks to library, in which i'am trying to remove top view of stack. Can anyone help me in this quistion ? Or mb any other libs can do this thing ? Thx

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards) library

Comment: i was trying this library first but i have a lot of bugs with it, sometimes onTouch method not work propertly... i want to upgrade this library with some methods, smth like removeTopCard() addTopCard() ... any ideas ?

Comment: You could copy the source and fix what you need

Comment: i know, i'am already copy it and lost a lot of time trying to understand how to do this thing. I have no any idea how to get topCardView from CardsStackView.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for https://github.com/lawloretienne/TinderStack